# Karate , how to mask Params from Post request login html CI report

Tags: cucumber, karate

I kept secure information like , Base url, USERID , Password, etc  in `Karate-config.js` file.

Karate-config.js  `params = {password = secrate, user=sachin}`

Feature file

```
Given  url URL
And path 'api/site/login'
When request params
And method post
```

I could hide secure information directly on html report but still these information in shown in log of help report for `post method`. please refer screenshot.

[image]

Please let me know how to hide this certain header information (only password and userid )?

Comment: Note : logback-test.xml is not a solution for my problem i tried that it just hide local logs.

Comment: if this part of the docs don't help, please assume this is not supported, and we look forward to a PR or two from you :) https://github.com/intuit/karate#log-masking

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas i am not working for DemoLogModifier() and basic-auth.js, in both ways we can mask when passing. I am looking for some solution which do not show  secure information from header

Comment: did you even look at the API ? it gives you a way to process headers before they are logged. if that doesn't work, you can either contribute code or look for another tool. and you can always hide the whole scenario or feature from the report if needed